# Populating Textboxes/DDls in Kendo Window on Click of Edit Of kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Im using Kendo Grid And Kendo Window.. On click of Edit in Kendo Grid, Need to populate a kendo window which consists of Textboxes.. Im not using the editable"popup" because there is a grid in Kendo Window. Anyways.. Here Is my Window

```
                        if (!window.data("kendoWindow")) {
                            window.kendoWindow({
                                visible: true
                                , resizable: false
                              //, content:' /api/Info/'
                                , modal: true
                                , actions: ["Close"],
                                close: function (e) {
                                }
                            });
                        }

                            window.data("kendoWindow").title(header);
                            window.data("kendoWindow").center();
                            window.data("kendoWindow").open();
                    }
```

Im currently getting Data from the selected Row of Kendo Grid. What I need to do is just populate the Kendo Window with the data.. I tried using the - content:"api/foo" But its not working.. I think I need to explicitly set the textBox values..How Do I do that?!
Please Help ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind selected row item (Observable Object) to Window Form.
Here are some links about value binding:

[Value Binding Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/index)

[Value binding API](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/value)

Comment: Hi it tryd,
    `case WindowMode.Update:
                {

                    editItem = kendo.observable({

                        action: function () {
                            var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                            var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                            debugger
                        editItem .set("txtName", selectedItem.Name);
                        }
                


                    })
                    kendo.bind($("#Item"), editItem );}`
But its of no use...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using templates with window. Set editable property in your grid:

```
editable: 
    {
        mode: "popup",
        window: {               
            animation: false,
            open: updateRowEventHandler
        }
    } // skip edit property, since that will open a custom popup
```

Then define eventHandler function for edit event:

```
function updateRowEventHandler(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); //prevent opening custom popup
     var uid = $(".k-edit-form-container").closest("[data-role=window]").data("uid");
     let model = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(uid);

     //pass model to a template
     let updateTemplate = kendo.template($("#updateDialog").html())(model);
     //initialize the window here
     let updateWindow = window.kendoWindow({
                            visible: true
                            , resizable: false
     ...
     //then pass your model to the template
     updateWindow.data("kendoWindow")
      .content(updateTemplate)
      .center().open();
```

The template should be look like this:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="updateDialog">
  <label>Label:</label>
  <input value="#= data.ModelPropertyYouPassed #" />
</script>
```